# How can I upload a file outside public_html?

Tags: php, public-html

I have a folder structure like this:

```
etc
files
public_html
tmp
```

I want users of my website to be able to upload files, and have those files stored inside the `files` folder (as opposed to storing them inside some folder within `public_html`). This is for security reasons. I'm a bit of a newbie, and I'm having trouble figuring out how to store the uploaded file to the `files` folder. Here is my code (the relevant part?):

```
$path = dirname( __FILE__ ) ."/" . 'files/my_file.pdf';
$success = move_uploaded_file( $tmp_name, $path );
```

How should I change `$path` to get this to work?

Comment: If you want to navigate backward, you can use two dots `..`

Comment: depends on what FRAMEWORK_PATH is, normally you just add two dots to say "one folder back"

Comment: So I would write ``../files/my_file.pdf``?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is hard to say where you files are being uploaded to with knowing what the value for `FRAMEWORK_PATH` is.  If you specifically want to put a file to the location of your choosing just specify it explicitly like:

```
$path = '/path/to/files/';
$filename = 'name_you_want_to_give_upload';

$success = move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $path . $filename);
```

Comment: OP should also make sure that the directory he/she wishes to upload to  is writeable by their web server.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to save a file outside where your **upload.php** files is, then you need to add `../` at the beaning of the file path where you wanna save it, eg:

if your **upload.php** files is in this root:

```
public_html/files/php/upload.php
```

but, your want to save your uploaded files on a folder which name is **upFiles** and it is outside the php folder *(which is this case)*, you may write the path like this:

```
../upFiles/
```

You can use this method if you want to save it on a sub-folder too:

```
../files/anotherFolder/upFiles
```